# Can I attach a storyboard to a Static Library

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard, static-libraries

I have a very simple single view application that I need to convert into a library.

I believe I am off to the correct start of going to my project settings and then adding a Cocoa Touch Static Library. After doing that I moved my ViewController.h, ViewController.m and Main.storyboard files to the new library directory.

I then went to my applications project settings and added my new library to the "Link Binary With Libraries". Then under the general tab I set the Main interface to nothing since I had moved the storyboard to the new library directory.

Then I went to my libraries project settings and add the Main.storyboard to the Copy Files.  Lastly I deleted the two default .h and .m files that were created when I added the library and then added the ViewController.m file to the libraries Compile sources.

The app loads a blank screen and gives warnings because it can't access any of the inputs on the storyboard.  How do I get library to load the storyboard or is this just completely wrong?

Comment: I was just pointed towards this guide that seems like it might be of help. http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/ so I am going through it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the application (not the library) is copying the storyboard.

You should probably build a [resource bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html) for your resources (a zipped file that ends with .bundle).

There is a hack you could try if you really want to get down to one file, [Embedded Frameworks](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework#embedded-framework).

> Although frameworks are an improvement over libraries, Xcode ignores any resources contained within frameworks. So if you have xibs, images, sounds, or other files in your framework, Xcode won't see them. An embedded framework is a way to trick Xcode into seeing the included resources.

You can see the structure [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-packager/issues/1).

```
KFData.embeddedframework
├── KFData.framework
│   ├── Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers
│   ├── KFData -> Versions/Current/KFData
│   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
│   └── Versions
│       ├── A
│       │   ├── Headers
│       │   │   ├── ..
│       │   ├── KFData
│       │   └── Resources
│       │       ├── ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
│       │       ├── Info.plist
│       │       ├── LICENSE
│       │       ├── KFData.bundle
│       │       │   ├── ..
│       │       ├── KFData.xcconfig
│       │       └── VERSION
│       └── Current -> A
└── Resources
    ├── KFData-Acknowledgements -> ../KFData.framework/Resources/ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
    ├── KFData-License -> ../KFData.framework/Resources/LICENSE
    ├── KFData-Version -> ../KFData.framework/Resources/VERSION
    ├── KFData.bundle -> ../KFData.framework/Resources/KFData.bundle
    └── KFData.xcconfig -> ../KFData.framework/Resources/KFData.xcconfig
```

Comment: Regarding the "hack" linked - This answer helped me a bit, but I had to [add a PR](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework/pull/218) to the linked repo to work with storyboards on Xcode 7.3.1 - posting here since the project is no longer maintained but still worked for me (with my fix).